# Segmentation algorithm to split a group of points based on their local linearity

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Suppose I have some points that roughly consist of N segments, each of which has some linearity between the points. The following example shows 3 clusters, but generally we don't know how many segments is proper. So which algorithm can be used to split a group of points into several segments based on the local linearity (i.e. the points inside one cluster are linearly related.)

picture one: the points. 
[image: picture]

picture 2: expected clusters: [image]

Comment: Very interesting problem that I don't know anything about. But finding a Euclidean minimum spanning tree and then partitioning that into subtrees of nearly colinear points seems like a useful approach.

Answer (score 1):

While you could try **correlation clustering** algorithms, I don't think you are looking at a clustering problem here.

Instead, look at time series **segmentation**. The difference is that clustering algorithms will consider points to be *independent*, but in your problem they stem from a *sequence*.

If you consider a X shape, you will probably want to segment this into four segments, but a clustering algorithm will consider this to be two linear clusters. Even worse, if you erase the center to have a data set like this:

```
\ /

/ \
```

it will still be *two* clusters to many correlation clustering algorithms, because two parts each *have* the exact same correlation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be outdated for you, but for future references, try using a Hough Transform.

If you know how many lines (N) you are searching for, apply a Hough Transform on your data set, extract the N highest peaks and then cluster points based on their proximity to each of the N lines.

I know this approach is not computationnaly efficient but you don't seem to have many points, so it shouldn't be a major issue here.